# Is there a logout_required equivalent to login_required in Django?

Tags: django

Django provides the very useful `@login_required` `views.py` decorator, which you can also call as a function (`login_required()`) in `urls.py`. It redirects a user without authentication to `settings.LOGIN_URL`.

Is there a similar decorator for `@logout_required`, such that the view is only rendered if the user is not authenticated, otherwise redirected to `settings.LOGOUT_URL` or equivalent?

Comment: No because logging out doesn't need user intervention, you can just log out the user in code (there's no such thing as a `LOGOUT_URL`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no buitlin one, since that does not restrict much: a user can simply log out and visit the view, so it will usually only make the site less convenient.

If you really want that, you can implement one, in a similar way as how [**`@login_required`** is implemented [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L38). For example with:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def logout_required(function=None, logout_url=settings.LOGOUT_URL):
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: not u.is_authenticated,
        login_url=logout_url
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

You here will need to define a `LOGOUT_URL` yourself in your settings, since otherwise accessing the `LOGOUT_URL` will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an if to do it.

```
def login_view(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('/main_url/')   ...
```